# Is it possible to connect to L2TP/IPsec in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, proxy

I have purchased a VPN. It has given me details like the following:

```
Username: dfasdaf241321
Password: gsddfid0aidoaso
nyc1-ubuntu-l2tp.myprovider.com
```

I am trying to use Switchy Omega as a Chrome extension to connect to it. However, there is no port number. Is it possible to connect to it like a normal proxy? By normal proxy, I mean a proxy which I could connect to in one Chrome profile only by using server_address, port_number, user_name, password?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

Proxy servers are not VPN servers. VPN servers are not proxy servers. Proxies carry HTTP requests and TCP streams, while VPNs carry IP packets. As the latter are handled by the OS and not by Chrome, it means the VPN connection itself has to be set up at OS level<sup>1</sup>.

That being said, "No port number" is not something to make assumptions out of. Many protocols have a *default* port number; it might simply be not specified if the server is running on the default port for that protocol. (For example, you don't see website links specifying that they're on port 443, because that's the standard HTTPS port anyway.)

In your example, L2TP *does* have a port number – it runs on UDP/1701 (and most likely it's encapsulated in IPsec ESP, which runs on UDP/4500 when NATs are involved) – but the service provider didn't specify that because all L2TP clients know what the default port is anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup> (unless Chrome decided to invent its own TCP/IP stack independent from the OS so that it could make the raw IP packets available to extensions – which probably isn't that far off for Google, but still extremely unlikely for apps in general)